# Why my "call sub" only run properly after the last one is choosing

Tags: vba, excel

I have a question about "call sub" function works different than I wanted. Thank you all in advance.

Here is my code:

```
Sub filter()
Dim i As Integer, x As Single, y As Single
    x = Worksheets("filter").Range("a2").Value
    y = Worksheets("filter").Range("c2").Value
    For i = 2 To 1000
        If Worksheets("speaker data").Cells(i, "d") = "l" Then
            Worksheets("speaker data").Cells(i, "n") = Worksheets("speaker data").Cells(i, "m") - 3 * Log(x) / Log(2#)
            Else
            Worksheets("speaker data").Cells(i, "n") = Worksheets("speaker data").Cells(i, "m") - 6 * Log(x) / Log(2#)
        End If
    Next i
    Call driver
    Call ways
    Call type
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$N$1000").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=">=" & y, _
    Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

The sub "driver","ways","type" are using the same auto filter, the only different is the auto filter filed. The problem I have is no matter what, I have to filter the last "call sub", then the top two can work properly. For the code above, I have to change "type" to "Y" or "N", but not All, then, the "ways", and "driver" will work perfectly. If the "call driver" at the bottom, then I have to change driver filter to "good" or "bad", but not all, then the rest of the filter can run properly.

I wonder why this would happen, the call sub code is like below:

```
Sub ways()
Worksheets("speaker data").Select
If Worksheets("filter").Range("a6") = "All" Then
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$N$1000").AutoFilter Field:=9
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$N$1000").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=Worksheets("filter").Range("A6").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm really appreciate all of your help.`enter code here`

Thank you all.

Comment: I'd like to help but your question & example are hard to understand.   Please check out [mcve].

Comment: It would be useful if you pasted your `Sub Type` code into the question.  As the answer from @thx1138v2 points out, it is impossible to create that subroutine so it would be interesting to see how you managed to do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
Call type
```

"type" is a key word in VBA. Replace it with "Kind".